# Differential equations for chemical reaction $\mathrm{A + 2B \to 3C}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chemistry

> In a chemical reaction $\mathrm{A + 2B \to 3C}$, the concentrations $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$ of the three substances A, B and C measure up to the differential equations
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \frac{da}{dt} &= -rab^2\tag{1}\\
> \frac{db}{dt} &= -2rab^2\tag{2}\\
> \frac{dc}{dt} &= -3rab^2\tag{3}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   with $r > 0$ and begin condition $a(0) = 1$ and $b(0) = 2$.
>
> Show that $b(t) - 2a(t) = 0$ .

Here is my solution, but it is not right. Any help would be great.

#### First equation

$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{da}{a} &= -rb^2\int dt\\
\ln(a) &= -rb^2t + C\\
a(t) &= e^{-rb^2t+ C}\\
a(0) &= 1 &&\to &1 &= e^{0 + C}\\
\ln(1) &= C &&\to &C &= 0\\
a(t) &= e^{-rb^2t}
\end{align}
$$

#### Second equation

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{db}{dt} &= -2rab^2\\  
\int \frac{db}{b^2} &= -2ra\int dt\\
b &= \frac{1}{2rat + C}\\
b(0) &= 2 \quad \to \quad 2 = \frac{1}{C} \quad \to \quad C = \frac{1}{2}\\
b(t) &= \frac{2}{ 2rat + 1}
\end{align}
$$

But now $b(t) - 2a(t) \ne  0$. Where I am making mistake? Any tip will be enough.

Comment: Equation (3) should read $$\frac{dc}{dt} = +3rab^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we shall show that $b-2a$ is constant, observe
$$\frac d{dt}(b-2a)= \frac{db}{dt}-2\frac{da}{dt} $$
And by the system.
$$\frac{db}{dt}-2\frac{da}{dt}=-2rab^2+2rab^2=0$$
Hence $b-2a$ is constant. And since
$$b(0)-2a(0)=2-2=0$$
We have $b-2a\equiv 0$

Or, you can also solve (“half of”) the equations. Since we have
$$\frac{da/dt}{db/dt}=\frac{-rab^2}{-2rab^2}=\frac12$$
Hence, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{da}{db}=\frac12\implies a=\frac12b+C_0$$
By the initial condition, we have, $C_0=0$, hence
$$b-2a=b-2\frac12b=0$$

Remark: by the second method presented above, you can actually solve for $b(t)$. I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, by your equations,

$\dfrac{d(2a - b)}{dt} = 2\dfrac{da}{dt} - \dfrac{db}{dt} = -2rab^2 -(-2rab^2) = 0; \tag 1$

hence $2a(t) - b(t)$ is constant.  Now

$2a(0) - b(0) = 2(1) - 2 = 0; \tag 2$

the desired result follows.

Comment: If i am not wrong then it's $b\prime (t) - 2a\prime (t) = 0$. ?

Comment: @afrazsalim:  you are not wrong, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your solution of the second equation: you forgot that the concentration $a(t)$ is a function of $t$, you are not allowed to pull it out before the integration sign.

Comment: And the same mistake is made in the solution to first equation, where $b^2$ is pulled out of the integral. This answer is correct, being the only one to point the source of the OP's mistake. I do not understand the downvote and the delete vote.